# Are there any program for showing tooltip via OCR

Tags: ocr

Edited for clarification based on comments:

At work we have an old developed program where I need to navigate on a very long dropdown list only with numbered codes. 
To select the correct code, I manually look at an excel list that shows the code and the name each codes corresponds with.

To make matters worse, it is not possible to type in the dropdown box (only first character is recognized when typing)

**So my question is:** Are there any program which can show the text from a predefined list, when i mouseover the various possibilities in the dropdown list?

The purpose would be to be able to identify the name which corresponds to each code, without having to look at the excel list.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you clarify the question a bit? I understand that you have 1) a list of codes and names and 2) a dropdown list of the codes only. But I'm not sure that's what you mean, and it took me a while to get there. And then, why don't you go the other way around? Use your descriptive list to find the code you want, then type it in the dropdown list?

Comment: Which application is this? One in particular or all?

Comment: m4573r - thanks for the questions, I've edited the question so the problem and purpose should be clearer. Is it more understandable now? English isn't my main language, and my problem is a bit complicated yes.

Comment: Way more clear now :) What's your environment? Which OS? I'm thinking that Autohotkey might help

Comment: Oh and please use `@m4573r` when replying, otherwise i'm not notified of any new comment.

Comment: @m4573r The OS is Windows XP. I have dabbled with Autohotkey a bit, I'm no programmer or AHK expert, but I can do some of the basics. I don't see how AHK could do something like this tho, but I guess I could try and see

Comment: @Casper - The only possible solution to your problem is to modify the program in question itself to do what you want.

Comment: There's a way to get the content of a dropdown list, there's a way to display a tooltip, and there's definitely a way to define a datastructure corresponding to your excel sheet. I have little time to look at it now but I'm pretty sure your problem can be solved using AHK.

Comment: @m4573r Thanks for the hint - I'll head over to the AKH forums and take a look if similar OCR stuff could be adapted.

Comment: @Ramhound That unfortunately is not an option. I'll try with autohoykey as m4573r suggested.